# Планировщик в GWT.

Tags: gwt, java

Нашел два похожих метода в Scheduler. Не могу понять, какой использовать. Оба работают как таймеры.
В чем разница между

```
  Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedPeriod(new Scheduler.RepeatingCommand() {
    public boolean execute() {
    }
  }, 100);
```

и

```
  Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new Scheduler.RepeatingCommand() {
    public boolean execute() {
    }
  }, 100);
```

Проверял, работают абсолютно одинаково. И еще вопрос: что будет, если в команде выпадет NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*scheduleFixedDelay* - отсчет указанного интервала времени начинается после завершения очередной задачи.

*scheduleFixedPeriod* - отсчет указанного интервала времени начинается сразу с момента запуска очередной задачи.